# Can you write a Google Apps script that will recognize a Form submit and reveal a Site navigation button?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sites

I'm creating a training program with sequential learning modules hosted on Google Sites. For one of them, I've embedded a Google Form onto the site page, and I also have navigation buttons on the page to move through the modules. Is it possible to write a Google Apps script that will hide the "next" navigation button (on the site), and reveal it once the user presses 'submit' on the embedded form?

I have a little bit of javascript experience but am brand new to Google Apps Script, so forgive me if this is a silly question- I haven't been able to figure this out from the documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: Highly unlikely.